# What does abstract path means in java.io?

Tags: java, file, io, path

In java doc about

```
File#getPath()
```

writes:

```
 Converts this abstract pathname into a pathname string.
```

I try to write1

```
File file3 = new File("D:\\work");
System.out.println(file3.getPath());
```

In cmd I see `D:\\work`

I try to write2:

```
File file4= new File("file4");
System.out.println(file4.getPath());
```

In cmd I see:

```
file4
```

Thus I have a question:

What the difference between

> abstract pathname

and

> pathname string

?

Comment: "abstract pathname" is a fancy way of saying "`File` object"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An *abstract pathname* is a `java.io.File` object and a *pathname string* is a `java.lang.String` object. Both reference the same file on the disk.

How do I know?

The first sentence of the Javadoc of `java.io.File` explains:

> An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames.

It goes on to explain why:

> User interfaces and operating systems use system-dependent
>   *pathname strings* to name files and directories.  This class
>   presents an abstract, system-independent view of hierarchical
>   pathnames.

Answer (score 2):

The abstract pathname is just the string form of the file/location held in the `File` object.

If you check the javadoc of `File#toString()`:

> Returns the pathname string of this abstract pathname. This is just the string returned by the `getPath()` method.

Answer (score 1):

See javadoc: abstract pathname = File

1. An optional system-dependent prefix string, such as a disk-drive specifier, "/" for the UNIX root directory, or "\\" for a Microsoft Windows UNC pathname, and
2. A sequence of zero or more string names. [refering to directories and file

These are independent of operating system peculiarities of notation.

The string form gives you what you need to write on your current operating system to refer to that file.